# Explanation on cmd commands

Tags: cmd

To start jboss on my system I need to type in this command in my cmd "run.bat -c main -b localhost". I couldn't figure out what does -c and -b do.

Comment: You should refer the documentation [https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/guides/installguide/r1/en/html/start-stop.html](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/guides/installguide/r1/en/html/start-stop.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question *is* specific to `JBoss`. The `-c main` specifies the configuration to use and the `-b localhost` specifies the binding address for all JBoss services.

That's for that *particular* command. If you want to know *generally* what `-x` options are (for varying values of `x`), that depends totally on the program you're running.

The arguments are simply given to the program and they can treat them as they see fit.

It's a convention that arguments starting with `-` are options of some description so you could end up with things like:

```
ls -l *.txt          # -l means long listing format.
ox -xcb infile.bin   # -xcb means hex, show characters, and byte-based output.

assignTo -user paxdiablo -property god-like-powers
                     # what I'd like to happen on Stack Overflow :-)
```